# Logout functionality throwing error C# winform

Tags: c#, winforms, logout

I have a Windows application wherein I want a logout functionality. I don't want the logout throwing the application on the login page as I don't have a login page. Login is just a panel on the main page.

I have tried the following code but it throws this error:

> error:Collection was modified enumeration operation may not execute.

```
private void mnulogout_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DialogResult dialogresult=MessageBox.Show("Do You Want To LogOut?","LogOut",MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question);
            if (dialogresult == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                foreach (Form fm in Application.OpenForms)
                {
                    fm.Close();
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: are you trying to show a panel on clicking log out?

Comment: yea i want to show the panel.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are invoking `Close` on elements of the container over which you are iterating. Since this container only contains open forms, the form will be removed from the container when you are calling the `Close` method, thus you are altering the container during iteration. C# does not like this.

To fix this, create a copy of your container and iterate over this copy:

```
List openFormsCopy = new List(Application.OpenForms);
foreach (Form fm in openFormsCopy)
{
    fm.Close();
}
```

Note that this only answers the C# portion of your problem. Some other answerers have suggested that you are iterating over the wrong collection anyway. I am not familiar with WinForms, so I cannot comment on that but you might want to look into it.

Answer (score 0):

if you are trying to show/hide panels that are in the same form you can use this

```
private void mnulogout_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DialogResult dialogresult=MessageBox.Show("Do You Want To LogOut?","LogOut",MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question);
            if (dialogresult == DialogResult.Yes)
            {                    
                loginPanel.Visible = true;
                OtherPanels.Visible = false;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're trying to close any child forms the parent form may have opened, you should be using `this.OwnedForms` rather than `Application.OpenForms`:

```
foreach (var form in this.OwnedForms)
{
    form.Close();
}
```